# sql query in php not returning what needs

Tags: php, oracle

I have this PHP page with a query, on the login page I need to enter user and password, the query will check username his type and floor, I'm not sure where is the problem, but it is, if a user is is "manager" and his floor is not 4, it return "One return", if a user is not manager and his floor is 4, it return "another return", but if user is not "manager" and his floor is not 4, it return "one return". I really can't understand how to solve this . I need: if user is not manager and his floor is 4 - return "One return", if user is manager it must return "another return", but if user is not manager and the floor is not 4, return nothing.
I appreciate any help

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
session_start();
include 'init.php';
$user = $_SESSION['user'];


$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select * from users where username = '$user' and user_type != 'manager' and floor = 4");
oci_execute($stid);
if (($user = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) == false){

    echo "One return";
}else{
    echo "another return";

}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Main Page</title>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You MUST use bind variables instead of text like `username = '$user'` otherwise you will have a SQL Injection security issue.  Check the OCI8 doc and/or http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html

Comment: Hi Christopher, if you can do it, I will change with pleasure, my homework deadline is tomorrow, so I must finish my rest of code. if no, thx for your comment, I will read it after deadline

Comment: I would fail my students who don't use bind variables :)

Comment: I understand, but my cours is sql, and not php, i don't know php, so 0.5% of my php knowledge is not included about security ( you cannot fail students, if you didn't tell them about this, right? ) =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the checks out of the query, and do them in the PHP code, so you can check for the different combinations. If you just check whether the query returned something or not, there's only two possibilities.

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select user_type, floor from users where username = '$user'");
oci_execute($stid);
$user = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
if (!$user) {
    echo "User not found";
} elseif ($user['user_type'] != 'manager' && $user['floor'] == 4) {
    echo "one return";
} elseif ($user['user_type'] == 'manager') {
    echo "another return";
}
```

Comment: In just few minutes you have solve my headache since beginning of this week. Thanks a LOT!!!

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? what if I want to return the first condition, the negation of !$user, is returning null, but what if I want to print "user not found"?. Thx again

Comment: Not sure I understand. The negation of `!$user` is just `$user`. But that will only be true when the query successfully fetches a row, which means the user was found.

Comment: I mean, when !$user, that is : user not found, and it's not printing something, but how to print something, like to print "user not found"

Comment: Oh, ok, I will just replace !$user, with : $user['user_type'] != 'manager' && $user['floor'] != 4, so I can print that user is not found

Comment: My code already prints user not found if the username isn't found. If the user is found but they're not a manager, it prints other things.

Comment: The suggested code is subject to SQL Injection security problems.  Use bind variables instead of string concatenation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php